# Change JComboBox selection on the basis of user confirmation

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

Is there any way to keep user on old selected option from JComboBox. There is one confirmation  I am asking to user when he/she wan't to change JComboBox's selected item, if user say yes, then only I want to keep new selection else set old item selected.

Is there any way to restrict JComboBox selection? I am using `ItemListener` and `MouseListener` to achieve above functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemListener` generally fires two events.  The first is a `DSESELECTED` event (the old value) and a `SELECTED` event (the new value).

You could monitor these changes, recording the `DESELECTED` value as they occur

As a test, you could try something like this...

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        System.out.println("Selected :" + e.getItem());
    } else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
        System.out.println("Deselected :" + e.getItem());
    }
}
```

If the user selects "no" to the change, you could restore the `DESELECTED` value...